# How to plot y axis directly on the right side, without using the axis command?

Tags: r, plot, axes

I am plotting forecasts at the end of a time series, so I think it is more convenient to have y ticks on the right, because they would be closer to the forecasted part of the path.

Is there a way to avoid to do this:

```
set.seed(1)

x <- 1:10
y <- sample(1:15, 10)

par(mar = c(5.1, 2.1, 4.1, 4.1))
plot(x, y, yaxt="n", ylab=NA)
axis(4)
mtext("my y", 4, line = 2)
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: you could switch to lattice, but it's probably a poor bet if your long-term plan is to save some typing (it requires about 1000 `?xyplot` calls per day).

Comment: yes, I thought about Lattice, but I wanted to check if someone had a quicker way to solve that.

Comment: you could always wrap those few commands into a custom plot function. That's where functional programming really shines through.

Comment: I believe I'll do like that, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could just construct a function that does what you like.

Start with something like this, and then customize it further if you want, for example, further control over which side the axis is plotted on, the number/placement of axis ticks, or whatever:

```
myPlot <- function(..., yaxt = "n", ylab = NA) {
    plot(x, y, yaxt = "n", ylab = NA)
    axis(4)
    mtext(ylab, 4, line = 2)
}

myPlot(x, y, ylab="my y")
```

Comment: saw your answer while I was posting mine, despite the overlap they're somewhat complementary so I'll leave mine for now.

Comment: @baptiste -- And I saw your second comment after I posted my answer. I'd have left the question alone if I'd known you were on the case ;).

Comment: yours is better and healthier, i've removed mine

Comment: @baptiste -- Yeah, I'd just come to the same conclusion myself.